# Integrar servidor samba4 ao microsoft active-directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

Tenho um server windows server 2003 em produção rodando como controlador de domínio, tenho as contas, grupos etc. tudo certinho e funcionando ali.

Eis que recebo aviso da microsoft que o server 2003 deixará de ser suportado pela microsoft [conforme todos já devem saber](http://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/)

Então comecei a testar a samba4 com suporte a *DC* (domain controller) e rodou muito bem, pode ser gerenciado pelo *RSAT* ( Remote Server Administration Tools ), só não sei como fazer agora essa parte de migrar as contas, grupos etc. do *DC* microsoft para esse feito em samba4, também ouvi dizer algo tipo promover um e/ou replicar, essa parte ai é que não sei fazer, na verdade não sei nem se isso é possível fazer dentro desse ambiente que tenho "samba4 <-> microsoft"

Answer (score -2):

Ola,
Este procedimento é bem simples. 
 1 - Ingressar o Samba 4 como DC do Win2003;
 2 - Transferir as ROLES e FSMO do Win2003 para o Samba 4, para que este seja o DC primário da rede;
 3 - Caso desejar, despromova o DC Windows 2003.

Segue o link:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Join_an_additional_Samba_DC_to_an_existing_Active_Directory

Comment: tente passar todo o conteudo necessário do link para o SOpt, pois assim se o link quebrar a resposta continuará válida.